# Redirecting http://www.example.com/index.html to http://www.example.com/ (without looping)

Tags: apache-2.2, http, url

For aesthetic reasons (I prefer when there is a strict one-to-one mapping between URL and pages), I do not like the fact that http://www.example.com/index.html and http://www.example.com/ yield the same content with two different URLs. I would like to have http://www.example.com/ as the canonical one.

The obvious solution:

```
Redirect permanent /index.html /
```

is wrong (endless loop).

A better solution? It seems surprisingly difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution (which seems to work so I accepted it), inspired from PP's response, is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/index\.html$
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/ [R=302,L]
```

Any non-modrewrite solution? I had to activate a new Apache module, which I try to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

Try a `RewriteCond` from [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^/$
RewriteRule /index.html / [R]
```

This says if the query string is *not* `/` then rewrite `/index.html` as `/` (should not loop).

Comment: Thanks, clearly the best solution (I adapted it a bit and, since I do not have enough points to edit your answer, I created mine).

Answer (score 1):

`RedirectMatch ^/index.html$ http://www.example.com/`

Comment: I tried and it loops endlessly.

Answer (score 1):

Why not set DirectoryIndex to something else - e.g., unpredictable.html, and name your index file similarly?

```
DirectoryIndex unpredictable.html
Redirect permanent /index.html http://yoursite/
```

You need never expose the chosen DirectoryIndex value.

Note that the last argument to Redirect needs to be a full URL, not just a path fragment.

Comment: Nice and clever idea but, still, if someone uses the /unpredictable.html URL, it will get to the content of the index page.

Answer (score 1):

A non mod_rewrite solution… Actually joschi nearly had it but for some (unclear to me) reason you have to kludge around the endless loop:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/index\.html$ http://www.example.com/
AliasMatch ^/$ /var/www/index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/index\.html$
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/ [R=302,L]
```

perfect solution

Comment: How is this any different than the accepted answer?